# What's the difference between Puyo Puyo Tetris and Puyo Puyo Tetris S?

Tags: version-differences, nintendo-switch, puyo-puyo-tetris

When I was looking for Puyo Puyo Tetris on Amazon, I saw a game called "Puyo Puyo Tetris S" ("ぷよぷよテトリスS"). It was a Japanese import.

I couldn't find much information about it online other than the fact that it was for Nintendo Switch only, and I even went as far as getting the demo for it, but the only difference I can see is that it's in Japanese (and that the vibrations are much stronger for some reason).

Is the only difference between them just regions? Was the game "Puyo Puyo Tetris S" simply re-released under the name "Puyo Puyo Tetris" to western audiences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Japan Puyo Puyo Tetris was released in 2014 for 3DS, Wii U, PS Vita, PlayStation 3. These versions had DLC available for purchase. Later on that year the PS4 and Xbox Ones versions were released with DLC included. The DLC included things like backgrounds, BGM, chapters, etc.

- [1st DLC release](https://web.archive.org/web/20140307025245/http://puyo.sega.jp/topics/2014/0206_02/index.html)
- [2nd DLC release](https://web.archive.org/web/20140312225129/http://puyo.sega.jp/topics/2014/0220_03/index.html)
- [3rd DLC release](https://web.archive.org/web/20140312225130/http://puyo.sega.jp/topics/2014/0306_02/index.html)

3 years later an updated version was released in the west for the PS4 and Nintendo Switch. Since Japan didn't already have a Switch version, it was also released there, but with a new title differentiating it from the other 6 console versions. Both of these versions included all the latest patches and DLC.

The western Switch release and Japanese release do no differ in any major way.

Answer (score 2):

The Nintendo Switch version is (for now) the definitive version of Puyo Puyo Tetris, due to the use of HD Rumble. The S was likely added in order to clearly mark it as such. In the West, the S was left out (possibly because in the West, the Switch version was released simultanously with the PS4 version), but it is the exact same game.

The sad thing is that some people mistakingly think that the Windows/Steam version is the definitive version of the game, because that version came out the last (and because high-end gaming PC's have more raw computational power than consoles, but Puyo Puyo Tetris does not benefit from that in any way). So maybe they should have kept the S.

Comment: So playing without any rumblable Controller would not be any different between the Tetris and Tetris S versions?